# restoring Postgres dump with tablespaces

Tags: postgresql, restore

I'm trying to restore a dump done with `pg_dumpall > mybak.sql` from a server that has 1 table in a different tablespace that the default one.

On the target machine I have recreated the directory structure of the tablespace and it is owned by the postgres user with read/write permissions but still the restore is failing. Any suggestions?

command used to restore is:

`psql mydb -f mybak.sql`

Thanks

Comment: I see that you managed to solve the problem, but when having errors and asking about them, it is always advisable to post the actual error message, too.

Comment: Yep, **always** include PostgreSQL version (`select version()`) and **exact text** of any error message.

Answer (score 1):

Got it,

had to recreate the tablespace manually on target before restoring the dump.

Thanks anyway